# Functor reference through a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Basically, I would like to have the following semantic :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class test
{
  public:
    void add(std::function<void()> f)
    {
      f();
    }

    void operator()()
    {
      ++x;
    }

    int x = 33;
};

int main()
{
  test t;
  t.add(t);
  // wanted: x == 34 instead: x == 33 since add(t) copies it
}
```

I understand std::function wraps a copy of the callable object but is there any way to get a reference to a callable object using std::function?

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using so that it shows up in the appropriate lists.

Comment: +1 for such a nice example for `std::ref()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to use the [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) template function to create a [reference wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) for your instance:

> `std::reference_wrapper` is a class template that wraps a reference in a
>   copyable, assignable object.
>
> Function templates `ref` and `cref` are helper functions that generate an
>   object of type `std::reference_wrapper`, using template argument
>   deduction to determine the template argument of the result.

You would use it like this:

```
t.add(std::ref(t));
```

Comment: Perfect :o This should be explained in online references :/

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to pass in a lambda - binding t as a reference:

```
t.add( [&t]{ t(); } );
```

This seems more readable to me (but only because I'm familiar with lambdas and not std::bind). The distinction is perhaps reminiscent of an item in Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++, #34: Prefer Lambdas to std::bind*.

Comment: In such a simple case, a lambda is readable and does work. But if the function has parameters and/or return value, it becomes more verbose.