# Using t( *this ) results RuntimeError, while t( std::ref( *this ) does not

Tags: c++

I have the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Tmr {
    typedef std::function<void(void)> Callback;
    Callback cb;

    Tmr(Callback cb_) :
        cb( cb_ )
    {
    }

    void timeout()
    {
        cb();
    }
};

struct Obj {
    struct Tmr t;

    Obj() :
        t( std::ref( *this ) )
    {
    }

    void operator () ()
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << '\n';
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Obj o;

    o.t.timeout();

    return 0;
}
```

This runs fine, but initially I had the constructor of `Obj` as:

```
Obj() :
    t( *this )
```

Which results in a runtime error. I guess this is because only a reference to the member function is stored in my callback, and not the object to call the member on.

What I don't understand is what `std::ref` does when I do `Obj() : t(std::ref(*this))` and why this makes the program work. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on and how it works ?

Comment: No `Obj() : t(*this)` works fine. Your `Callback` is a functor type, which your `Obj` also is.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Are you saying the compiler generates invalid code, since `Obj() : t(*this)`  crashes at runtime , but it should work fine ?

Comment: It works on my g++ std c++11 compiler, and I can't see why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Does it help if you mark `operator()` as `const`?

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336790/functor-reference-through-a-stdfunction

Comment: Whatever, `std::ref` is a wrapper that construct an object to encapsulate a reference to some object. It is used when you want to store a reference in a container for example (which you normally can't).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It does NOT work on my g++ 5.3.1/linux 32 bit nor in VS 2015 (Note that the whole example, as mentioned, works fine.) Did you change the constructor so it reads `Obj() : t(*this)` instead of `Obj() : t(std::ref(*this))`  ?

Comment: @AlanStokes No, marking operator() as const doesn't change anything. It generates a Illegal instruction (core dumped) on linux and a 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC. in MSVC

Comment: As `*this` is under construction at that time, is it really surprising that its value can be invalid ...?

Comment: @Ilya There are numerous question here on SO, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869281/passing-this-from-constructor-initializer-list , that says it would be fine. Or are those answers wrong, or is there something with my code here that makes them not apply ?

Comment: @binary01 you're not passing `this`, you're passing `*this`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you don't pass by reference you're copying `*this` before `t` has been initialised - which means you're copying `t` and its callback member before they've been initialised, which is undefined behaviour.

(And the copy constructor of `std::function` is likely to try to copy what's pointed to by an uninitialised pointer, which is what causes the actual crash.)

Answer (score 1):

You code crashes because of copying of uninitialized Callback object. You can see a sequence of event below:

```
1. Copy constructor of Obj is called in t(*this)
2. Copy constructor of Tmr is called as t is a member of Obj
3. Copy constructor of Callback is called as cb is a member of Tmr
4. Execution fails while trying to copy from uninitialized Callback object.
```

By using std::ref you bypass a copy creation of Obj; that's why it doesn't crash.